# Gulp, mocha and istanbul - not capturing tests

Tags: node.js, gulp, mocha.js, istanbul

I am trying to write a Gulp file that will run my mocha tests and also generate code coverage using Istanbul.  Everything runs fine, but the coverage report shows that basically nothing is covered (and almost all of it is).  The gulpfile.js is below:

```
var gulp     = require('gulp');
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var mocha    = require('gulp-mocha');

gulp.task('pre-test', function () {
    return gulp.src(['utilities/helpers.js'])
        .pipe(istanbul(
            {includeUntested: true}
        ))
        .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire());
});

gulp.task('test', ['pre-test'], function () {
    return gulp.src(['test/utilities/helpers.spec.js'])
        .pipe(mocha({
            reporter: 'spec'
        }))
        .pipe(istanbul.writeReports({
            reporters: ['text', 'clover', 'html']
        }));
});
```

The report generated shows (with 24 passing tests):

```
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
 utilities/  |        0 |      100 |      100 |        0 |                |
  helpers.js |        0 |      100 |      100 |        0 |... 57,58,62,67 |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files    |        0 |      100 |      100 |        0 |                |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

Comment: As a test I also ran this through nyc and get a 88.24% coverage on statements, 100% on branches, 84.21% on functions and 88.24% on lines.  I can't seem to get nyc to run in gulp though...only on command line.